# Why $A \to A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a characteristic zero ring.

Why $A \to A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is injective and what is tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ meaning here ?

Can someone briefly explain the importance of tensor product on which I have weakness.

I want to understand the basic concept.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about where you've found this claim and what you already know? The question sounds like a simple homework exercise, but in comments to on answer it sounds like you're really asking to have tensor products explained from the ground up -- which you wouldn't need to if you had a textbook that does that already. So what's going on here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, sir, the simple answer is- I am learning and I quoted it from a textbook as I have weekness in tensor product

Comment: In that case it is vitally important to **explain what you already know and what it is that confuses you**. Simply demanding to have things explained from the ground up is rude to people who answer -- they have no way of even _trying_ to make their answers different from the textbook that didn't work for you. You're essentially asking them to "keep explaining this in random ways until you by pure chance find one that works for me", all while you're refusing to provide any insight into what it is you find difficult about the subject, or even which kind of explanations _don't_ work for you.

Comment: (And calling random people on the internet who are not paid for being here "sir" is pretty rude too. "Sir" is something you call an overbearing bully who demands random displays of obsequiousness from you -- using it on a total stanger means "I think you are an overbearing bully, and I will treat you as such". If you want strangers to help you in their free time, at least have the common courtesy to speak to them like equals).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Tensor product:  Let $R$ be a  commutative ring  and let $U, V$ be two $R$-modules. Then the tensor product $ U \otimes_R V$ means another $R$-module together with a billinear  map $\phi: U \times V \to U \otimes _R V$ satisfying $f=g \circ \phi$ where $f: U \times V \to W$ and $g : U \otimes V \to W$ and $W$ is $R$-module

Comment: You are completely missing the crucial part of the definition, namely what's up with $f$ and $g$. The definition requires that _for every_ $W$ and $f$ _there must be one and only one_ $g$ such that bla bla bla. Without that explanation the definition just becomes random nonsense. Go reread your textbook and make sure to take note of _each time the definition is used_ how the particular relation between $f$ and $g$ comes into play.

Comment: @HenningMakholm,  I use 'Sir' to respect unknowns  in any platform. Here education is a place of respect and I did nothing wrong by saying 'sir'. But if you think me wrong then I apologize

Comment: If you think it is okay to treat strangers _who are trying to help you_ as if they are overbearing bullies who demand empty displays of obsequiousness from you, then good luck. I'm done here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, oh sorry, here $f,g$ are billiear maps

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thank you very much for pointing the crucial part of the definition. This helped me

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Assume $A = M_2(\Bbb{Z})$ then $A = \sum_{j=1}^4 \Bbb{Z}b_j$ for some matrices $b_j$ (those with only one $1$) then $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q \cong \sum_{j=1}^4 \Bbb{Q}b_j$ a group, a $\Bbb{Q}$ vector space of dimension $4$, and a ring with the multiplication of the $b_j$ defined as in $A$. In general the tensor product  $A \otimes_R  B$ is the idea of "taking a $R$-module basis for $A$ and instead of taking the coefficients in $R$ take them in $B$" in a formal way defined by the $R$-bilinearity laws of $\otimes_R$.

Comment: @reuns, thanks for contributing. It was precious comment from you. It helped me lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an Abelian group under addition. Then $A\otimes \Bbb Q$
means $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$, the tensor product of $A$ and $\Bbb Q$
of these groups considered as $\Bbb Z$-modules. Then $a\mapsto a\otimes 1$
is a group homomorphism from $A$ to $A\otimes \Bbb Q$ whose kernel
is the torsion of $A$. So $A\mapsto A\otimes\Bbb Q$ is injective iff $A$
is torsion free.

If in addition $A$ is a commutative ring, then $A\otimes \Bbb Q$ is
a commutative $\Bbb Q$-algebra.

If you are asking why consider such tensor products, suppose $A$ is a ring.
Then each ring homomorphism $\phi:A\to B$ where $B$ is a $\Bbb Q$-algebra
factors uniquely through $i:A\mapsto A\otimes\Bbb Q$, that is $\phi
=\psi\circ i$ where $\psi$ is a uniquely determined homomorphism
from $A\otimes\Bbb Q$ to $B$.

Comment: here $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ means tensor product of the two on $\mathbb{Z}$. How does this  tensor product operates ? Can you explain because I have lack in basic concept of tensor product

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer

Comment: why kernel is torsion of A?

Answer (score 5):

No one has yet written a counterexample, so I am now writing one below.

The map $- \otimes 1:A \to A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} {\mathbb{Q}}$ is not necessarily injective even if $A$ has characteristic zero. For example, the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$ is a ring of characteristic zero with a non-torsion-free additive group, so the map "tensor with 1" is not injective in this case.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$, which is of characteristc $2$. How do we get characteristic $0$ ?

Comment: You are confusing the ideal $(2x)$ with the ideal $(2,x)$. The quotient by the latter (which is not principal) is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which obviously has characteristic two. The quotient by the former (which is principal), on the other hand, has characteristic zero because the former does not contain any nonzero constant polynomial.

Comment: oh sorry, thanks